# SqlServer Exception Encountered "VARCHAR"

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sqlexception

I'm getting this error that doesn't allow me to create a table. It says that there is a syntax error.

Code:

```
@Override
public void create() throws SQLException {
    String sqlString = String
            .format("create table %s(%s VARCHAR(20), %s VARCHAR(20), %s VARCHAR(50), %s VARCHAR(20), %s VARCHAR(5), %s VARCHAR(10), %s VARCHAR(20), %s VARCHAR(20), primary key (%s) )",
                    _tableName, ID, DESCRIPTION, STREET, CITY, PROVINCE, POSTALCODE, STOREPHONE, AUTOSERVICEPHONE, ID);
    super.create(sqlString);
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "VARCHAR" at line 1, column 133.
...
```

Comment: Are ID, DESCRIPTION etc. constant fields?

Comment: @ChetterHummin yes they are

Answer (score 2):

An educated guess, but one if your variables is almost certainly blank, or contains a blank.

Ordinarily I'd make this a comment, but it's the only possible cause I can think of.

Print out the SQL string to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape your column name, in case some of your column name is reserved word in SQL.

```
@Override
public void create() throws SQLException {
    String sqlString = String
            .format("create table [%s] ([%s] VARCHAR(20), [%s] VARCHAR(20)......
```